# JavaFx: Check current position of PathTransition while running

Tags: java, graphics, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to get the current position (x,y) of a Circle (javafx.scene.shape.Circle) i am moving via a PathTransition, while the transition is running/happening.

So i need some kind of task, that checks the position of the circle every 50 milliseconds (for example).

I also tried this solution [Current circle position of javafx transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780781/current-circle-position-of-javafx-transition) which was suggested on Stack Overflow, but i didn't seem to work for me.

```
Circle projectile = new Circle(Playground.PROJECTILE_SIZE, Playground.PROJECTILE_COLOR);

root.getChildren().add(projectile);

double duration = distance / Playground.PROJECTILE_SPEED;

double xOff = (0.5-Math.random())*Playground.WEAPON_OFFSET;
double yOff = (0.5-Math.random())*Playground.WEAPON_OFFSET;

Line shotLine = new Line(player.getCurrentX(), player.getCurrentY(), aimLine.getEndX() + xOff, aimLine.getEndY() + yOff);

shotLine.setEndX(shotLine.getEndX() + (Math.random()*Playground.WEAPON_OFFSET));

PathTransition pt = new PathTransition(Duration.seconds(duration), shotLine, projectile);

// Linear movement for linear speed
pt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

pt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // Remove bullet after hit/expiration
    projectile.setVisible(false);
    root.getChildren().remove(projectile);
    }
});

projectile.translateXProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    double x = collider.getTranslateX() - projectile.getTranslateX();
    double y = collider.getTranslateY() - projectile.getTranslateY();

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));

    System.out.println("Distance: "+ distance);

    if (distance < 50) {
        System.out.println("hit");
    }
    }
});

pt.play();
```

Comment: The `PathTransition` just changes the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the node being transitioned, so you can just register a listener with those properties and do whatever you need any time they change.

Comment: Okay thx, can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Well, can you post some sample code from your transition I can work with? Why do you need the position, for example?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm trying to check, if a moving "projectile" (=circle) is hitting another object 'collider'.

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work, though it's difficult to know for sure without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PathTransition` will move a node by manipulating its `translateX` and `translateY` properties. (A `TranslateTransition` works the same way.)

It's hard to answer your question definitively as your code is so incomplete, but if the `projectile` and `collider` have the same parent in the scene graph, converting the initial coordinates of the `projectile` and `collider` by calling `localToParent` will give the coordinates in the parent, including the translation. So you can observe the `translateX` and `translateY` properties and use that conversion to check for a collision. If they have different parents, you can do the same with `localToScene` instead and just convert both to coordinates relative to the scene.

Here's a quick SSCCE. Use the left and right arrows to aim, space to shoot:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ShootingGame extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final double width = 400 ;
        final double height = 400 ;

        final double targetRadius = 25 ;
        final double projectileRadius = 5 ;

        final double weaponLength = 25 ;

        final double weaponX = width / 2 ;
        final double weaponStartY = height ;
        final double weaponEndY = height - weaponLength ;

        final double targetStartX = targetRadius ;
        final double targetY = targetRadius * 2 ;;

        Pane root = new Pane();
        Circle target = new Circle(targetStartX, targetY, targetRadius, Color.BLUE);
        TranslateTransition targetMotion = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), target);
        targetMotion.setByX(350);
        targetMotion.setAutoReverse(true);
        targetMotion.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        targetMotion.play();

        Line weapon = new Line(weaponX, weaponStartY, weaponX, weaponEndY);
        weapon.setStrokeWidth(5);
        Rotate weaponRotation = new Rotate(0, weaponX, weaponStartY);
        weapon.getTransforms().add(weaponRotation);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                weaponRotation.setAngle(Math.max(-45, weaponRotation.getAngle() - 2));
            }
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                weaponRotation.setAngle(Math.min(45, weaponRotation.getAngle() + 2));
            }
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {

                Point2D weaponEnd = weapon.localToParent(weaponX, weaponEndY);

                Circle projectile = new Circle(weaponEnd.getX(), weaponEnd.getY(), projectileRadius);

                TranslateTransition shot = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), projectile);
                shot.setByX(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(weaponRotation.getAngle())) * height);
                shot.setByY(-height);
                shot.setOnFinished(event -> root.getChildren().remove(projectile));

                BooleanBinding hit = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
                    Point2D targetLocation = target.localToParent(targetStartX, targetY);
                    Point2D projectileLocation = projectile.localToParent(weaponEnd);
                    return (targetLocation.distance(projectileLocation) < targetRadius + projectileRadius) ;
                }, projectile.translateXProperty(), projectile.translateYProperty());

                hit.addListener((obs, wasHit, isNowHit) -> {
                    if (isNowHit) {
                        System.out.println("Hit");
                        root.getChildren().remove(projectile);
                        root.getChildren().remove(target);
                        targetMotion.stop();
                        shot.stop();
                    }
                });

                root.getChildren().add(projectile);
                shot.play();
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(target, weapon);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```